# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\sardo\\Downloads\\ChicagoCensusData.csv')

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, read-csv

I am running this code in Jupyter Notebook

```
df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\sardo\Downloads\ChicagoCensusData.csv')
df.to_sql("CENSUS_DATA", con, if_exists='replace', index=False, method='mutli')
```

I tried these methods:

1. `df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\sardo\Downloads\ChicagoCensusData.csv')`
2. `df = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\sardo\Downloads\ChicagoCensusData.csv')`
3. `df = pd.read_csv('ChicagoCensusData.csv')`
4. All of the above, with double quotes and forward slash

But error showing:
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\sardo\\Downloads\\ChicagoCensusData.csv')`
Why double backslash? and Where is the problem? Help me

Comment: The simple answer is that the file really, truly, **does not exist**.  You're using the wrong filename or a wrong directory name.  (The double backslashes are an artifact of how Python handles backslashes in strings.  They're not important.)

Comment: Use this code to see the true contents of that directory `import os; print(os.listdir(r'C:\Users\sardo\Downloads'))`

Comment: Hi, I find where the problem is. I was using Jupyter Notebook online, as it is given by IBM Data Science course on Coursera. When I used the locally on my computer, everything is good, no error is showing. I think there is a problem in server of course. Thank you!

Comment: @JohnGordon the file exists!

Comment: "I was using Jupyter Notebook online, as it is given by IBM Data Science course on Coursera." That statement should have been in the original post. "I think there is a problem in server of course." About that...There'd be a major security problem if the Jupyter running on a remote machine in your browser could see the hierarchy of your drive and access the files without you allowing this some way first. Option number #3 that you listed as trying should work **if you first upload the data file** to the remote machine and place it alongside your notebook.

Comment: @Wayne oh, that works thank you, after uploading the file, it works!!!

Comment: Also, even if there is no actual remote machine and your course is using JupyterLite (you'd probably see pyodide kernel indicated in this case), you should think of the place it is computing in the browser as de facto 'remote' machine. The way JupyterLite works **at present** is that is has a separate file place inside your browser storage/cache area it uses. In that case you have to place the data file into the same directory where the notebook is running by dragging it into the file browser panel on the left. (Ignore this entire comment if JupyterLite isn't involved.)

Answer (score 1):

The double back slashes are because the backslash itself marks special characters, like the newline (`\n`), so to use it as text it has to escape itself as `\\`, but using the `r" ... "` type string avoids that entriely so you should be good to use single slashes so long as you have the `r" ... "` type string. However, if it's throwing an error saying the file doesn't exist, then there's a chance the slashes arent the issue. If you're on windows you can shift+right click the file and there should be an option on the prompt to "copy as path" -- paste that inside of `r" ... "` and see if it still throws the error when reading the CSV. Otherwise, it could be a permissions issue where the python instance is denied access to that particular file.

Comment: Hi, I find where the problem is. I was using Jupyter Notebook online, as it is given by IBM Data Science course on Coursera. When I used the locally on my computer, everything is good, no error is showing. I think there is a problem with online server in course. Thank you!